# Java generics: the type parameter T is hiding the type T

Tags: java, generics

Why java compiler is giving me "the type parameter T is hiding the type T" in the "translate" method ?

```
public static interface Translator<T, E> {
  E call(T t);
}

public static <T, E> List<E> translate(List<T> l, Translator<T, E> t) {
  ..
}
```

If i remove the type parameter T

```
public static <E> List<E> translate(List<T> l, Translator<T, E> t)
```

the warning disappeared but now i cannot do

```
List<Long> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> r = translate(l, new Translator<Long, String>() { .. })
```

cause it give me this error

```
The method translate(List<T>, GFn.Translator<T,E>) 
in the type GList is not applicable for the arguments 
(List<Long>, new GFn.Translator<Long,String>(){})
```

Comment: Is the function translate defined outside of the interface?

Comment: Have you got a concrete class / entity anywhere named `T`?

Comment: @Nessuno, it should be, as interfaces can't have method bodies untill java 8, which ain't released yet. And a static interface looks awkward to me.

Comment: @svz You are right of course. I was thinking of an abstract class...

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code and don't get any warning messages:

```
public class Main {

public static interface Translator<T, E> {
    E call(T t);
}

public static <T, E> List<E> translate(List<T> l, Translator<T, E> t) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    for (T item: l) {
        result.add(t.call(item));
    }
    return result;
}

public static class TranslatorImpl implements Translator<Long, String> {

    @Override
    public String call(Long aLong) {
        return String.valueOf(aLong);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Long> items = new ArrayList<Long>();
    items.add(10L);
    items.add(20L);
    items.add(30L);
    System.out.println(translate(items, new TranslatorImpl()));
}
```

}

Comment: i checked with anonymous implementation and still no warnings

Answer (score 0):

I used JDK 1.7 and the following code just works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

interface Translator<T, E>
{
    E call(T t);

}

class LongToStringTranslator implements Translator<Long, String>
{

    @Override
    public String call(Long t)
    {
        return t.toString();
    }

}

public class Main
{
    public static <T, E> List<E> translate(List<T> l, Translator<T, E> t)
    {
        List<E> e = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T item : l) {
            e.add(t.call(item));
        }
        return e;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Long> l = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);
        List<String> s = translate(l, new LongToStringTranslator());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but was a mistake of mine, the problem was in a function after that one that was wrong:

```
public static void walk(Iterable<T> list, Walker<T> walker)
```

This mas missing the T type parameter, if i correct it

```
public static <T> void walk(Iterable<T> list, Walker<T> walker)
```

All the warnings disappears in all other methods in my class.

Thanks and sorry to all.